# How can I get an image from another application

Tags: android, image-processing

I have an app what do something with pictures.
It can make pictures and write it to the `sdcard` or pic an image from the gallery.

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` I have this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

So my app will be found as a destination for pictures. So far so good.
But what next now?
Where is the picture, what an other app share to my app?

---

thanks for your help. This may be the problem (AndroidManifest.xml). Where i must put the intent ? I have 2 Activities. The first is the login whitout image manipulations, the second is the one, who wants to see the image (dashboard).
But i must first log in, before use my dashboard activity, so i cant call the dashboard direct.
Also i have this Code put into login onCreate Methode, but it always returns null -if i "share" an image via gllery to my app or something (on normal startup it is clear, that it will be null).

LoginActivity.java

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    if(getIntent().getData() != null){
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        File image = new File(uri.toString());
        Log.d("jnLoginURI",image.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        Log.d("jnLoginURI","uri=null");
    }
    // ...............
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.owndms.owndmsandroid2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/owndms"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".DashboardActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="ownDMS"
            android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

btw: pick an image from gallery or make image from camera works in my dashboard activity.

Comment: you have defined the filter for activity ,now the defined activity will get the the call when user choose to select your apps to open it images, and you will get the path and file name via "getIntent()" I intent.

Comment: My app will open from the other app, who share the image. But the result sill is null. Im confused.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Activity` where you add the `Intent-Filter` on the `AndroidManifest.xml`, you should obtain the data shared (the image) from the `Intent`.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name="MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**MyActivity:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        if(getIntent().getData() != null){
            try {
                Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
                InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**res/layout/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, 
i get always null from uri. 
In the AndroidManifest.xml is the intent in the right section (loginActivity) and in this loginActivity JavaClass i have your code.
Jan

Comment: still the same. uri is null. Is it right to put this code in the onCreate methode ?

Comment: When is uri `null`? when you share an image? I have tried this and isn't null ... only is null when you open the `Activity` without share and image

Comment: My app will be open from the other app, who share the image. But the result sill is null. Im confused.

Comment: Hi, i think the manifest is the Problem. I have 2 intent-filter sections.

<intent-filter >
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>

If i put it together, the launcher tells me:
"No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!"

Comment: If we applyi simple logic, then `android.intent.action.SEND` is not what should be declared int he manifest file, since `SEND` means sending, i.e YOUR_APP -> WORLD. So, this same logic suggests that there should be `android.intent.action.RECEIVE` action to be able to receive intents WORLD -> YOUR_APP. I am correct?